# In this code can you please explain what is happening after the draw(n -1) function

Tags: recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void draw(int n);

 int main(void)
 {
    int height = get_int("number:");
    draw(height);

 }
 void draw(int n)
 {
   if(n <= 0)
   {
      return;
   }
   draw(n - 1);
   for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
   {
      printf("#");
   }
   printf("\n");
 }
```

Iam learing recursion topic, suppose the user input 4 when the compiler completes the if part the value of **n** is '0' and returning when **i** debug ,  but then the for loop starts the value of '**n**' becomes '1' and also '**i**' doesn't change it constantly 0 why is that  iam expected **n** becomes 0 after the if draw(n - 1) completes.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make this explanation as simple as I can. First things first, To begin with, when using recursion, you would be noticing the calling of a method within itself with a different argument. In your case it is the draw method.
Now each time, a draw method is called inside another draw method, the outer method(in this case the draw that is called first) stops its flow of execution till the completion of the inner draw.
So when you called draw(4), it ran all the code till it reached line 5 in draw  method, and called draw(3). Your for loop of draw(4) is not executed yet. This will continue till draw(1) calls a draw(0). At this stage, draw(0) will return out and the draw(1) will continue its for loop from where it left. So you would find that here n=1, leading to the first print of # and then a new line after it. Once the operation completes in here, it continues with where it left for draw(2). Which is the for loop in draw(2) where the value of n=2. And here it does two print of # and then a new line. This continues.

Now for the question why i is always 0, it is to do with what we call scopes in programming, you can see that each time the i is declared fresh in the loop and assigned a value 0. This means, each time a for loop is hit, the value of i is reinitialised to 0. If you had a global var i out side of your draw method, you would have had the value of i being retained.

I did try my best to put things in as simple form as possible but feel free to let me know if you needed more clarity.

Comment: Happy to help. If you do accept the answer please don;t mind me asking for upvoting or choosing it as the right answer. :o) Appreciate it and thanks in advance.